# How to create a list of empty lists

Tags: python, list

Apologies if this has been answered before, but I couldn't find a similar question on here.

I am pretty new to Python and what I am trying to create is as follows:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
results = [list1, list2]
```

This code works absolutely fine, but I was wondering if there was a quicker way to do this in one line.

I tried the following, which didn't work, but I hope it demonstrates the sort of thing that I'm after:

```
result = [list1[], list2[]]
```

Also, in terms of complexity, would having it on one line really make any difference? Or would it be three assignments in either case?

Comment: results = [list1, list2] = [[], []]

Answer (score 64, accepted):

For manually creating a specified number of lists, this would be good:

```
empty_list = [ [], [], ..... ]
```

In case, you want to generate a bigger number of lists, then putting it inside a for loop would be good:

```
empty_lists = [ [] for _ in range(n) ]
```

Answer (score 188):

For arbitrary length lists, you can use `[ [] for _ in range(N) ]`

*Do not* use `[ [] ] * N`, as that will result in the list containing the *same list object* `N` times

Comment: This answer is more helpful than the accepted one because it explains why we should not use `[ [] ] * N`

Comment: ```[[] for _ in range(N)]``` confirms to better coding style, since, the index variable is ignored.

Comment: I wish I had known this earlier. I made exactly this mistake and was badly bitten by a bug and had to debug it for several hours. sigh :(

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm you then get very supprising results when you try to append a value to one of the lists....

Answer (score 3):

If you want a one-liner you can just do:

```
result = [[],[]]
```

Comment: Also `result = [list(), list()]`, but just a tip, `[[], []]` is more clear.

Comment: Great, thanks everyone. As an addition to this, If I have a list of lists as follows:
    
    `list = [[firstName, 1,],[secondName,2],[thirdName,3]]`

How can I access just the actual numbers? So for instance, if I wanted to find out the highest number out of:

    `list[0][1]
    list[1][1]
    list[2][1]`

What would the command be for that? Presumably something to do with `max()`?

Comment: @daemon_headmaster that should be posted as a whole other question, but you could do it like this: `max([i[1] for i in list])`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using numpy because you can build higher-dimensional list of lists as well:

```
import numpy as np
LIST = np.zeros( [2,3] )# OR np.zeros( [2,3,6] )
```

It works in any number of dimensions.

Comment: This is not what the questions asks for. This creates a list of lists with zeros, not a list of empty lists.

Comment: That builds a Numpy array, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [[],[]]
```

or

```
results = [list(), list()]
```