# Creating a dictionary with a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

```
generic_list = ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5', 'F6']
empty_dict = [{}]
generic_CT_curves_month = [np.datetime64('2022-12-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-03-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-05-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-07-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-10-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')]
generic_curves_dict = dict(zip(generic_list, empty_dict * 6))
print(generic_curves_dict)
for ticker in generic_curves_dict:
    generic_curves_dict[str(ticker)]['month'] = generic_CT_curves_month[int(ticker[-1])-1]
    
generic_curves_dict
```

output:

```
{'A1': {'month': numpy.datetime64('2023-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')},
 'B2': {'month': numpy.datetime64('2023-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')},
 'C3': {'month': numpy.datetime64('2023-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')},
 'D4': {'month': numpy.datetime64('2023-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')},
 'E5': {'month': numpy.datetime64('2023-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')},
 'F6': {'month': numpy.datetime64('2023-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')}}
```

I want generic_curves_dict['A1']['month'] to call the first date from generic_CT_curves_month and so on. How do I do that?

Comment: `empty_dict * 6` causes the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990673/how-to-create-a-list-of-empty-lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a very good attempt that almost works except for a few tricky details. It boils down to dictionaries being mutable in python, and the fact that `empty_dict * 6` copies a reference to the same mutable dictionary 6 times.

In your for loop, `generic_CT_curves_month[int(ticker[-1])-1]` does give the correct date time, but `generic_curves_dict['B1']` refers to a second reference to the same dictionary as `generic_curves_dict['A1']` so each cycle overwrites the month value in all 6 dictionaries. (To see this try `print([id(d) for d in generic_curves_dict.values()])`. It will show that each dict points to the same spot in memory).

There are a few ways to solve this. One would be to define `generic_curves_dict` in another way:

```py
# generic_curves_dict = dict(zip(generic_list, empty_dict * 6))
generic_curves_dict = dict(zip(generic_list, [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]))
```

Alternatively, dict comprehensions could come in handy too.

```py
import numpy as np

generic_list = ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5', 'F6']
generic_CT_curves_month = [np.datetime64('2022-12-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-03-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-05-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-07-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-10-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')]
generic_curves_dict = {ticker: {"month": generic_CT_curves_month[int(ticker[-1]) - 1]} for ticker in generic_list}
print(generic_curves_dict)
```

p.s. Are you intentionally stripping the number from the tickers A1 -> 1, etc. or will the dates always be in the same order as the tickers? For this particular example you could also use `enumerate` to iterate through the index and value of each ticker but not sure if that is a universal solution for your case

```py
import numpy as np

generic_list = ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5', 'F6']
generic_CT_curves_month = [np.datetime64('2022-12-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-03-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-05-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-07-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-10-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
                                  np.datetime64('2023-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')]
generic_curves_dict = {ticker: {"month": generic_CT_curves_month[i]} for i, ticker in enumerate(generic_list)}
print(generic_curves_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for this very comprehensive reply. Currently the dates are hardcoded, but I'll eventually want to extract them from an existing database so they should always be in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to generate the required `generic_curves_dict`

Also read more about what the zip function [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```py
generic_curves_dict = {k: dict(month=v) for (k,v) in zip(*[generic_list, generic_CT_curves_month])}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to build this dictionary

```
generic_curves_dict = {k: {'month': v} for k,v in zip(generic_list, generic_CT_curves_month)}
```