# How to store data in a double dimensional array in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I was coding a Python solver to find the Empirical Formula of a compound based on the information provided by the User. I wrote the following code:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))

data = [[""]*5]*n

for i in range(n):
    print("Enter the symbol of element, percentage and atomic number: ")
    for j in range(3):
        data[i][j] = input()

print(data)
```

Upon running the code, I expected that the data would be stored as I had given the program, but this was the output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFHzS.png)

Please help me out as I am unable to understand where I am going wrong with my code. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: `[[""]*5]*n` --> `[[""]*3]*n` share the expected output pls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a list of empty lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990673/how-to-create-a-list-of-empty-lists)

Comment: @balderman same problem - that creates a list containing n references to the same inner list, not a list containing n independent inner lists.

Comment: Specifically in this case, `data=[[""]*5 for _ in range(n)]` will do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not have native multi-dimensional arrays.
One way of achieving this, is by using lists inside lists  -  however, since lists start empty, you can't simply create a list inside a list, and expect to be able to store an item at `mylist[2][1]` - because that element does not exist yet.

So, you have to first, create your "list of lists" - a simple function can do that:

```
def array2d(m, n):
    return [[None for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
```

This has a similar effect to your attempt on doing
`data = [[""]*5]*n`  -but that will istead re-use the list objects created in the subexpression `[[""] * 5]` for all n-rows: all rows will refer to the *same* inner list, and changing one element will affect all rows at once:

```
In [61]: n = 3

In [62]: data = [[""]*5]*n

In [63]: data[0][1] = 5

In [64]: data
Out[64]: [['', 5, '', '', ''], ['', 5, '', '', ''], ['', 5, '', '', '']]
```

The usage of two `for` expressions ensures new lists are created for each row.

Another option is, instead of using a list of lists, using a dictionary. Since tuples can be dictionary keys, you can just use:

```
myarray = {}
myarray[3,2] = 5

print(myarray.get((3,2), 0))
```

It will work. If you use the `.get` method instead of retrieving the element with `myarray[3, 2]`, you can provide a default value (`0` in the example above) for the cases the position has no defined value.

The downside of using a dictionary is that there are no boundary checks, and one can request, or put values, into any position.

For both cases, in more sophisticated use, it is worth actually defining a class, defining the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods: that class will internally use either a list of lists or a dictionary, but then it can provide a lot of useful things, like boundary checking, default values, matrix multiplication operations, and so on.